# Is it possible to build a Large Memory System for matlab?

Tags: matlab, memory

I am suffering from the out of memory problem in mablab.
Is is possible to build a large memory system for matlab(e.g. 64GB ram)?

If yes, what do I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Itamar gives good advice about how MATLAB requires contiguous memory to store arrays, and about good practices in memory management such as chunking your data. In particular, the technical note on memory management that he links to is a great resource. However much memory your machine has, these are always sensible things to do.

Nevertheless, there are many applications of MATLAB that will never be solved by these tips, as the datasets are just too large; and it is also clearly true that having a machine with much more RAM can address these issues.

(By the way, it's also sometimes the case that it's cheaper to just buy a new machine with more RAM than it is to pay the MATLAB developer to make all the memory optimizations they could - but that's for you to decide).

It's not difficult to access large amounts of memory with MATLAB. If you have a Windows or Linux machine with 64GB (or more) - it will obviously need to be running a 64-bit OS - MATLAB will be able to access it. I've come across plenty of MATLAB users who are doing this. If you know what you're doing you can build your own machine, or nowadays you can just buy a machine that size of the shelf from [Dell](http://www.dell.com/uk/enterprise/p/precision-t7500/pd?~ck=anav).

Another option (depending on your application) would be to look into getting a small cluster, and using [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/) together with [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/).

Comment: Thanks for the information! I have checked out Dell's page, the machine is too powerful. I need large memory only, I don't care about the computation power. Anyway Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful. The machine from Dell was just an example to show that large machines are readily available - not a recommendation for Dell at all, or for that particular machine. I'm surprised to hear you say that you're not interested in computational power though - typically if you have a dataset large enough to need a lot of storage, you would also need a reasonable level of computational power in order to do anything with the dataset in a tolerable length of time.

Answer (score 3):

When you try to allocate an array in Matlab, Matlab must have enough contiguous memory the size of the array, and if not enough contiguous memory is available, you will get `out of memory` error, no matter how much RAM you have on your computer.

From my experience, the solution will not come from dealing directly with memory-related properties of your hardware, but from writing your code in a way that prevents allocation of too large arrays (cutting data to chunks, etc.). If you can describe your code and the task you try to solve, it might be possible to guide you in that direction.

You can read more here:http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1106.html

Comment: I will try to make the array small but it is quite hard for me to do so. Anyway Thanks!

Comment: That was only an example. Consider working with single precision (Matlab's default is double => 2 times memory allocation), or algebraically eliminating some intermediate results, etc..